# Doctrine and custom Oracle REGEXP_LIKE

Tags: sql, oracle, doctrine

I need to use Oracle specific function REGEXP_LIKE with Doctrine ORM. I wrote that function in Doctrine manner:

```
class RegexpLike extends FunctionNode
{
    public $expression;

    public $pattern;

    /**
     * getSql
     *
     * @param SqlWalker $sqlWalker
     * @access public
     * @return string
     * @throws \Doctrine\ORM\Query\QueryException
     */
    public function getSql(SqlWalker $sqlWalker)
    {
        return 'REGEXP_LIKE(' .
            $this->expression->dispatch($sqlWalker) . ',' .
            $this->pattern->dispatch($sqlWalker) .
            ')';
    }

    /**
     * parse
     *
     * @param Parser $parser
     * @return void
     * @throws \Doctrine\ORM\Query\QueryException
     * @access public
     */
    public function parse(Parser $parser)
    {
        $parser->match(Lexer::T_IDENTIFIER);
        $parser->match(Lexer::T_OPEN_PARENTHESIS);
        $this->expression = $parser->StringPrimary();
        $parser->match(Lexer::T_COMMA);
        $this->pattern = $parser->StringPrimary();
        $parser->match(Lexer::T_CLOSE_PARENTHESIS);
    }

}
```

After that I registered `RegexpLike` function in *string_functions* of Doctrine.
I tried use that function in this way:

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('i', 'i.id');

        $qb
            ->innerJoin('\App\Entity\Company','c', Join::WITH, 'c.id = i.sellerCompanyId')
            ->innerJoin('\App\Entity\Structure','s', Join::WITH, 's.companyId = c.id')
            ->innerJoin('\App\Entity\Person','p', Join::WITH, 'p.structureId = s.id')
            ->where($qb->expr()->andX(
                $qb->expr()->eq('p.id', '?1'),
                $qb->expr()->eq('c.id', '?2'),
                $qb->expr()->eq('MONTH(i.sellingDate)', '?3'),
                $qb->expr()->eq('YEAR(i.sellingDate)', '?4')
            ))
            ->andWhere('REGEXP_LIKE(i.invoiceNumber, :pattern)')
            ->setParameters([
                1 => $employeeId,
                2 => $companyId,
                3 => $month,
                4 => $year,
                'pattern' => '^F\/([0-9]{1,6})\/([0-9]{1,6})\/([0-9]{4})$'
            ]);
```

`$qb->getDQL()` returns query, which looks correctly:

```
SELECT i FROM App\Entity\BuyingOrderInvoice i INDEX BY i.id 
INNER JOIN \App\Entity\Company c WITH c.id = i.sellerCompanyId 
INNER JOIN \App\Entity\Structure s WITH s.companyId = c.id 
INNER JOIN \App\Entity\Person p WITH p.structureId = s.id 
WHERE p.id = ?1 
AND c.id = ?2
AND MONTH(i.sellingDate) = ?3 
AND YEAR(i.sellingDate) = ?4 
AND REGEXP_LIKE(i.invoiceNumber, :pattern)
```

but when I want display/execute SQL I get error:

*[Syntax Error] line 0, col -1: Error: Expected =, <, <=, <>, >, >=, !=, got end of string.*

Other custom functions (MONTH, YEAR) work perfectly, there is a problem only with REGEXP_LIKE.

I think it happens because in line `REGEXP_LIKE(i.invoiceNumber, :pattern)` there is no any comparison.

The query above without lines 
`->andWhere('REGEXP_LIKE(i.invoiceNumber, :pattern)')` and 
`'pattern' => '^F\/([0-9]{1,6})\/([0-9]{1,6})\/([0-9]{4})$'` works correctly.

How should I apply that function? Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: `number` is an invalid identifier, since it's a reserved keyword in Oracle. Are you sure of having a column called `number`..?

Comment: You are right, actually the column name is "invoiceNumber", I wrote "name" for simplicity, but it was bad idea

Comment: `SELECT i FROM App\Entity\BuyingOrderInvoice` - no backslash before `App`. `INNER JOIN \App\Entity\Company` has a backslash before `App`. ???

Comment: I update my post, the query without REGEXP_LIKE part works correctly